# If I override a method in a derived class, should I declare it again in the derived class' header?

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, overriding

I am learning Objective-C. In an exercise in my book, I will create a *Person* class and an *Employee* class that derives from *Person*.

**Person.h**

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) float heightInMeters;
@property (nonatomic) int weightInKilos;

- (float)bodyMassIndex;

@end
```

**Person.m**

```
@implementation Person

- (float)bodyMassIndex
{
    return self.weightInKilos / (self.heightInMeters * self.heightInMeters);
}

@end
```

**Employee.h**

```
@interface Employee : Person

@property (nonatomic) int employeeID;

@end
```

**Employee.m**

```
@implementation Employee

- (float)bodyMassIndex
{
    return [super bodyMassIndex] * 0.9;
}

@end
```

My book says, because *Employee* inherits from *Person*, everyone already know that *Employee* has a method named *bodyMassIndex*, so there is no need to advertise it again (in Employee.h). I have tried both with and without the extra declaration, and both ways work.

My question is, should you avoid declaring it again? Which way is most stylish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, avoid redeclaring it. If you wander around Apple's header files, you'll see that's what they do.

There are rare exceptions where a redeclare makes something clearer, but that kind of judgement will come with experience. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't redeclare it, because it is extra, unnecessary, redundant code. Also if for some reason you had to change the method signature, it's one more place you need to change it, and also one more place for you to forget to change it, so it would be a good idea to avoid this unnecessary duplication. It's the same with `@synthesize` no longer being necessary in most cases - don't do it anymore, because it's unnecessary extra code that you might forget to update when you change other things.

That being said, Clay Bridges makes a good point in his answer that there are rare cases where it makes sense, but usually you learn that with experience, and if you're unsure, that likely means to leave it off. I would likely only do it if it were a method very important and relevant to my class that was originally declared not in the direct superclass but somewhere farther up the chain, that I wanted to be sure people knew mattered.